# Border around an element including heading and paragraph. Heading on top border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi can anyone plz help me to achieve the effect shown in the attached image? I need to draw border around the element but its heading should be placed on top border as shown in image. It should be responsive, so i dont think nagative margin top for heading will not work.

[image]

Comment: What about trying a fieldset?

Comment: @Marcel - styling fieldset legends consistently cross browser can be challenging to say the least!

Comment: why not negative margin will do?? It will be responsive. The 'Regular' text will always be in the middle. What else you want in terms of responsiveness?

Comment: As the content inside element will be dynamic i cant fix width of the div. So I guess the heading will go up and down. So i thought nagative top margins will not work.

Comment: Try this  http://jsfiddle.net/libinn11/bp2tzLxz/

Comment: @ Libin align="center" will be a good way to align? align attribute is deprecated right?